# How to Create custom increment id like sales order increment_id for custom module

Tags: magento-1, eav, increment-id

I want custom increment_id field in custom module. Like sales_flat_order increment_id. Is EAV table format is best solution?

Comment: You can create in normal table as well

Comment: set your increment_id in before save method if object don't have id on it

Answer (score 1):

1. Add installer in your custom module to create new entity

```
$installer->addEntityType('qquoteadv', array(
    'entity_model'          => 'qquoteadv/qqadvcustomer',
    'table'                 => 'quoteadv/customer',
    'increment_model'       => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
    'increment_per_store'   => true
));
```

where quoteadv/customer - custom table will contain increment_id field.

2. Add Numeric.php in your custom module.

```
   public function getNextId()
        {                
                $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
                $nextNum = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getEntityType($aEntityTypes)
                    ->fetchNewIncrementId($storeId);
                $rowPrefix = Mage::getStoreConfig(self::PARAM_PREFIX);               

                return $this->format($nextNum);

            } else {
                return parent::getNextId();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this in flat tables not in EAV like structure you can do by just following step

> Your table needs to have store_id and increment_id field

In `config.xml` files `resources` node add this

```
<alias_setup>
   <setup>
      <module>Package_Module</module>
      <class>Package_Module_Model_Resource_Setup</class> <!--add this class-->
   </setup>
   <connection>
       <use>core_setup</use>
   </connection>
</alias_setup>
```

create `Package_Module_Model_Resource_Setup` class in respective location

```
<?php 
class Package_Module_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
{  

}
```

In your installer/Upgrade script add following code

```
$installer->addEntityType('yourentityname', array(
    'entity_model'          => 'model_alias/model', //entity model same as table in flat table case 
    'table'                 => 'model_alias/model',
    'increment_model'       => 'eav/entity_increment_numeric',
    'increment_per_store'   => true
));
```

in resource model class add following method

```
protected function _beforeSave(Mage_Core_Model_Abstract $object)
{
    if (!$object->getIncrementId()) {
        /* @var $entityType Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Type */
        $entityType = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_type')->loadByCode('yourentityname');
        $object->setIncrementId($entityType->fetchNewIncrementId($object->getStoreId()));
    }
    parent::_beforeSave($object);
    return $this;
}
```